# Unable to pass correctly an argument in a template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this inside "web/templates/module/headerHC.html.eex":

```
   <%= for element <- MyProject.PageView.Recursion.buildElements(@header_linkNumber),1) do %>
            <%= element %>
   <% end %>
```

Then, I use this component in "web/layout/HC.html.eex":

```
<%= render FabricaASA.ModuleView, "headerHC.html", conn: @conn,
    header_class: nil,
    header_linkNumber: "3"
%>
```

Finally I've defined inside "web/views/page_view.ex":

```
defmodule Recursion do
        def buildElements(n) when n <= 1 do
            [n]
        end
        def buildElements(n) do
            [n | buildElements(n - 1)]
        end
    end
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error:

`bad argument in arithmetic expression` pointing to this line:

```
def buildElements(n) when n <= 1 do
```

This happens when I insert `@header_linkNumber` instead of a number like `<%= for element <- MyProject.PageView.Recursion.buildElements(2),1) do %>`

I've already tried to use `@MyProject.ModuleView.header_linkNumber` instead but then I get this error:

```
cannot set attribute @__aliases__ inside function/macro
```

Comment: Do you use header_linkNumber as the argument to buildElements? If so, you should pass `3` and not `"3"`

Comment: Right! I missed the string there...Thanks Gazler (make that an answer, please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting "bad argument in arithmetic expression" as you are subtracting an integer from a string:

```
iex> "3" - 1 
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
    :erlang.-("3", 1)
```

Change:

```
header_linkNumber: "3"
```

To:

```
header_linkNumber: 2
```

As an interesting side note, you can actually compare strings to integers:

```
iex> "3" <= 1
false
```

You should be aware of this as it could cause unexpected errors if you are using strings instead of integers somewhere else.

The order (from http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-operators.html) is:

> number < atom < reference < functions < port < pid < tuple < maps < list < bitstring